# Verify color in Katalon Recorder

Tags: testing, automated-tests, background-color, katalon-recorder

Hi,

I would like to check that the color of a button is the expected color. I don’t know exactly which command I have to use in Katalon Recorder.

Here my element:

```
<ux-badge typeclass="success" class="ng-star-inserted">
<span class="ux-badge ux-badge--success ux-badge--pill ux-badge--small" data-e2e="ux-badge">Open</span>
</ux-badge>
```

Here my css style:

```
ux-badge--success {
    background-color: rgb(70, 122, 57);
}
```

Could you please help me with that ?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

**Step 1:** Create a variable

Command:`storeEval`

Target: `getComputedStyle(document.querySelector(".ux-badge--success")).backgroundColor`

Value: `background`

**Step 2:** Evaluate the variable

Command:`assertEval`

Target: `"${background}" == "rgb(70, 122, 57)"`

Value: `true`